# Android app runs on emulator, but the app can't be found on it

Tags: android

I recently ran into an interesting issue, which I am starting to understand a bit better now. I am building a small android application for learning purposes. If I run the application on genymotion or the normal emulator, it will launch and I can test it fine. Now, I noticed two things recently. First, when I look for the app in the device I can't find it anywhere to launch it, but when I look in the app section of the settings panel it is installed. Also, when my app crashes if I hit OK, I stop getting logs printed. Actually if I hit OK after the message notifying me that my application has crashed all previous Logs are erased. This has become annoying as trying to open my app after going to the homescreen and reading errors requires adds too many intermediate steps.

I did notice that all of my other applications install fine on the emulator, so I think it may have something to do with the project configurations. I went into the configurations and everything seems fine. Deploy default APK is selected, so I can't figure out what's going on.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file here?

Comment: Will add it in a second. Could anyone explained to me why is the question being downvoted? I tried to give detailed information about my application and it really doesn't make sense as to why it's being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vesko!

I checked my activity and for some reason I really can't understand the activity wasn't set as the MAIN activity in the manifest file. I am pretty sure this might've occurred after I deleted the original main activity to try some things.

Comment: Exactly, that's the reason I asked you to put your AndroidManifest file here. Glad your problem is solved :)